# Passing a structure member to a function in C

Tags: c, structure

I have a structure

```
static struct menu_item menu[] = {
    {1, "More memory"},
    {2, "Less memory"},
    {3, "Test"},
    {4, "Auto-allocate"},
    {5, "Test2"},
    {6, "Exit"},
    {0, ""}
};
```

I need to call a function which takes 2 parameters `(int, struct menu_item *)`. I need to pass the third element as a parameter to the function. int should be the selection no of the menu and the second parameter should be `Test`. How do I do it?

Comment: question is ambiguous, you want to call a 2 parameter function and pass third element?

Comment: Doesn't `foo(2, &menu[2])` work?

Comment: do not be in hurry to ask question, plz improve your question.

Comment: Your code is not valid C. You have not specified a struct name. Have you declared your struct somewhere?

Comment: i need to call a function , testFunc(int, struct menu_item *).

Comment: @Sid: Code makes no sense, rendering question useless.

Comment: then use `switch` construct e.g. if first parameter is `3` call `myThirdFunc()`

Comment: @aniket It looks like he's trying to pass the third element of the ARRAY to the function and he's not sure how to go about doing it.

Comment: +1 remyabel. **If** he's asking how to pass a composite (struct) element as parameter to a function expecting two distinct, plain data parameters, the answer is "not at all". The question being as it is, that's guesswork however.

Comment: @timrau: thanks for the reply but it didn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, this should be a straight-forward task. However due to zero-based indexing you need to pass `2` to the function.

```
typedef struct menu_item
{
    int n;
    const char* name;
} menu_item;

static struct menu_item menu[] = {
    {1, "More memory"},
    {2, "Less memory"},
    {3, "Test"},
    {4, "Auto-allocate"},
    {5, "Test2"},
    {6, "Exit"},
    {0, ""}
};

#include <stdio.h>

void func(int n, struct menu_item* menu)
{
    menu_item item = menu[n];
    printf("%d %s", menu[n].n, menu[n].name);
}

int main()
{
    func(2, menu);
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work at all. i get an error saying "expected 'struct menu_item *' but argument is of type 'struct menu_item'".

Comment: @Sid Did you run my program standalone? I typedef'd it so depending on how your struct is defined, it may have incompatible pointers.

Comment: `func(2, &menu);` in the `main()` function will be the correction

Comment: i implemented this thing in my code and it is running now. thanks @remyabel